# Using cursor for update inside a prepared statement

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, cursor, prepared-statement

I have the following cursor that I am using inside a JDBC prepared statement as follows:

```
DECLARE c CURSOR GLOBAL FORWARD_ONLY DYNAMIC SCROLL_LOCKS TYPE_WARNING 
FOR 
SELECT TxtPtr = TEXTPTR(PT.BODY), Src = N'ReplaceString', 
Offset = PATINDEX(N'%[^A-Za-z0-9]SearchThis[^A-Za-z0-9]%', PT.BODY) 
FROM       dbo.BODYCONTENT AS PT    
WHERE       PT.BODY LIKE N'%[^A-Za-z0-9]SearchThis[^A-Za-z0-9]%';
OPEN c;
DECLARE @Ptr binary(16), @Src nvarchar(50), @Offset integer;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @Ptr, @Src, @Offset;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE dbo.BODYCONTENT SET BODY = ltrim(rtrim(replace
(replace(replace(N' ' + cast(BODY as nvarchar(max)) + N' ','    
','<>'),'>' + @Offset + '<','>' + @Src+ '<'),'<>',' '))) 
from dbo.BODYCONTENT
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @Ptr, @Src, @Offset;
END;CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;
```

When I execute the above cursor directly in the database, it works only if explicitly give the values for `@Src` and `@Offset` as `'>SearchThis<','>ReplaceString<'`

How can I use `@Src` and `@Offset` in the query?

JDBC prepared statement:

```
String sql3 = "DECLARE c CURSOR GLOBAL FORWARD_ONLY DYNAMIC 
                SCROLL_LOCKS TYPE_WARNING FOR" +    
              " SELECT TxtPtr = TEXTPTR(PT.BODY), Src = N'+ ? + ', 
               Offset = PATINDEX(N'%[^A-Za-z0-9] + ? + [^A-Za-z0-9]%', PT.BODY)" +
               " FROM dbo.BODYCONTENT AS PT" + 
               " WHERE PT.BODY LIKE N'%[^A-Za-z0-9]?[^A-Za-z0-9]%';" + 
               " OPEN c;" + 
               " DECLARE @Ptr binary(16), @Src nvarchar(50), @Offset    
                  integer;" + 
               " FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @Ptr, @Src, @Offset;" + 
               " WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0" + 
               " BEGIN" + 
               " BEGIN TRANSACTION;" + 
               " UPDATE dbo.BODYCONTENT SET BODY = ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(N' ' + cast(BODY as nvarchar(max)) + N' ',' ','<>'),'>' + @Offset +'<','>' + @Src + '<'),'<>',' '))) from dbo.BODYCONTENT" + 
        "COMMIT TRANSACTION;" + 
        "FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @Ptr, @Src, @Offset;" + 
        "END;CLOSE c; DEALLOCATE c;";



pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);



            pstmt.setNString(1, searchStr);
            pstmt.setNString(2, replaceString);
            pstmt.setNString(3, searchStr);


            pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

How should I implement this?

I am thinking the problem is where I give the `?` for the parameters to be set by `setNString`. There is no problem with the cursor itself, the cursor works fine with hard coded values. But I want to be able to pass in the parameters in the java application from the config files using `setNString` or something similar.

Comment: Firstly, you should get rid of your cursor. The update is a bit confusing because you do the update on every row, not just the one from the cursor. But you need to think set-base, not procedurally-based, when you are working in a sql database. Refactor the query into a simple `update table set blah where blah`

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to understand all your patindex and replace strings (because my brain exploded), it should be a simple cursor-less update statement like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.BODYCONTENT SET BODY = ltrim(rtrim(replace
(replace(replace(N' ' + cast(BODY as nvarchar(max)) + N' ','    
','<>'),'>' + PATINDEX(N'%[^A-Za-z0-9]SearchThis[^A-Za-z0-9]%', PT.BODY)  + '<','>' + N'ReplaceString'+ '<'),'<>',' '))) 
from dbo.BODYCONTENT
WHERE PT.BODY LIKE N'%[^A-Za-z0-9]SearchThis[^A-Za-z0-9]%';
```

Comment: Hi TomC, Thanks for your reply. But the problem is I am trying to use Parameterized Query. My cursor works well when I hard code the Strings - 'SearchThis' and 'ReplaceString'. But the problem is when I try to use setNString or setString, it is not working.